# In multivariate regression, under what condtions is $var(X_i\epsilon_i')$ positive definite?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, least-squares, covariance-matrix, multivariate-regression

Suppose we have $(Y_i, X_i)$, with $Y_i$ an r.v. in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $X_i$ an r.v. in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and suppose the covariance matrix of $X_i$, $E(XX')$ is positive definite. Now we can estimate the (matrix of) multivariate regression coefficients that minimize the mean squared error as $\beta = E(Y_iX_i')E(X_iX_i')^{-1}$.

Now we can define $\epsilon_i := Y_i -\beta X_i$. My question is, what conditions on $(Y_i, X_i)$ are sufficient for $M:= Var(X_i \epsilon_i') = Var(vec(X_i\epsilon_i')$ to be positive definite?

What are some good resources in this area?

Comment: One (trivial) sufficient condition is conditional homoskedasticity (together with your assumption that E[XX'] is positive definite).

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I was hoping some conditions on $Y_i$ and $X_i$ (separately) could ensure this...